# dwarfdump command not found

Tags: ios, xcode4, command

Mac OS 10.8, xcode 4.4

When I want to execute the command :
dwarfdump --lookup 0x30f425e8 --arch armv7 XyzDemo.app.dSYM

I got the error : **dwarfdump: command not found**

Can anybody help me ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: just a guess - have you installed the command line tools via Xcodes settings?

Comment: thanks Pfitz, i'm not installed the command line tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Use dwarfdump command, you need installed the Command Line Tools via Xcodes settings

Thanks Pfitz!